# Get GridViewColumn item from MouseEnter

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I have `ListView` and `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Name">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter">
                <CheckBox  Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
                           Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <Binding Path="IsSelected" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}"/>
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

So as you can see i added `StackPanel` `MouseEnter` event:

```
private void StackPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So my question is inside this `StackPanel_MouseEnter` function: how can i get the current object that inside this `GridViewColumn` ? (or even the current index from my `ListView`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current item that this row is bound to (so, the item to which `Name` you bind your `TextBlock` for example) by accessing `DataContext` of your stack panel:

```
private void StackPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    var item = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as YourItem;
    if (item != null) {
        // do stuff   
    }            
}
```